# MVC selectable GridView

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am designing a webpage using **MVC**. One of the pages has the following controls and functions:

Controls:

- 2 GridViews (gvItems, gvSelectedItems)
- 3 buttons (btnTransferSingle, btnTransferAll, submit)

Functions

- gvItems will be populated with a set of items that contains: Name, points
- gvSelectedItems will contain items that is transferred from gvItems. Hence it will also contain: Name, points
- both GirdViews supports multiple selection
- btnTransferSingle will transfer all selected items from gvItems to gvSelectedItems.
- btnTransferAll will transfer all remaining items from gvItems to gvSelectedItems.
- btnSubmit will send all the items from gvSelectedItems to the Controller.

I am not sure how to the following:

- 1) How to create a gridview that supports multiselection and displaying of multiple model attribute.
- 2) How to transfer the items from one gridview (gvItems) to another (gvSelectedItems)?
- 3) How to pass back all the items from gvSelectedItems to the controller?

I am able to do the stuff that was mentioned using listBox but listBox only allows displaying of only one attribute and doesn't have a header.

I used Matt Kruse Javascript's Toolbox to aid the moving of items between listboxes.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that listboxes are the correct approach here.

If you want to display both attributes try to concatenate them when loading the data.
Headers can be somewhat added with html/css

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am hook up with other stuff and have to KIV this thing until now.

What you state can be applicable but it seems like list box doesn't allows you to use tab so its hard to differentiate the items. currently, I am using " - " to separate the items but it's still not really clear cut.

Beside this, I am not sure how to add headers to listbox using css.

Any links to help me to place "tab" inside the listbox item text and creating listbox heades using css?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to insert a tab character inside a HTML component, as in webpages the use of tab key is reserved to navigate between different components. It's a pitty. To circumvent this problem you could try to use two different listbox elements containing the data and showing each one a different attribute. This way you'll have your data tabbed. For the headers you'll need to write the headers out of the listboxes, just on the normal flow of the page positioned on top of the listbox elements.